# Cassandra: No column definition found for column error

Tags: cassandra, pentaho, kettle

I'm a newbie to Cassandra. I tried to insert a log file into Cassandra using the GUI tool Spoon, by Pentaho Data Integration. The file has the following fields. Timestamp, process_id, IP, child_id, dev_id, filter_level_id, uh, URL. The log file did not have a header. So i typed in these column names in the file and loaded it to Cassandra using the tool. But when i tried to create an index for the field IP using cql3, I got the following error.

No column definition found for column ip

Am I doing something wrong? How can this be resolved?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: here you mention IP while creating , and while getting error you mention small ip, in cassandra it matters to use the same name..

your question is not very clear, you created the keyspace and column family?

and have you checked the output while clicking on "cql to execute before inserting first row" under schema options in cassandra output step..

Comment: @WorkingHard: As mentioned, I used 'IP' while creation. But in the error I get, it is mentioned as 'ip'. I followed the below video to write the data into Cassandra. http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Write+Data+To+Cassandra.

Comment: Also, can you please explain more about checking the output while clicking on "cql to execute before inserting first row"?

Comment: main problem is you are trying with cql3 and following steps of cli..

Comment: for analyzing "cql to execute before inserting first row" your have to integrate (big data pluggin)http://shahumang.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/big-data-pluggin-in-pentaho-data-integration-client-4-4/ .. after this when you select cassandra output step it will be different compare to what it looks for now.. and their under schema options you will find "ql to execute before inserting first row"..

Comment: @WorkingHard: Hi. Thanks for your help. I have integrated the big data plugin with the pdi-client as mentioned by you. Under schema options, i checked the 'execute cql query before inserting first row'. But I still don't have any idea how to proceed. When I tried to create an index, again got an error, "Syntax error at position 7: No viable alternative at input 'index'". Where am i going wrong?

Comment: under write options select use select cql version3, your problem will solve. CLI and CQL both wroks differently, so search for solutions of CQL not CLI.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. It still doesn't solve the problem.. after i selected use cql version 3 and run the transformation, it throws error. When I clicked on show schema, I get the error, "An error occurred while getting the schema information::

null". I don't know if this could be useful, but I downloaded only the PDI client and used it for writing into the Cassandra database.